# Which columns of table in mysql should be declared as fields of entity in solr document?

Tags: solr

I am trying to import a mysql database into a solr document using xml, and am currently going through examples to learn and do so. But, I am not able to understand why some columns of a table are not declared as fields in an entity in the data-config.xml.
Also am i required to download Oracle jdbc server to use dih to import mysql database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only fields that should go into Solr are the ones you're actually planning on searching on. This might be 'most of them' or even 'all of them', but it can be a subset. For example, if your database contains a something like a sales catalog, you'd most likely have a `products` table in your MySQL database that looks something like this:

```
+----------------+
| products       |
+----------------+
| name           |
| brand          |
| description    |
| weight         |
| availability   |
| price          |
| shipping       |
| photo          |
| warehouse      |
+----------------+
```

Now, people will not go searching your site for that product they were looking for in Warehouse 32B, or that one product weighing exactly 3.23kg. They're looking for a "koenig lawnmower" or whatever.

In this case, you'd probably index only the first three columns (probably as two fields, one for name and brand and one for description).

This is why you have to define the fields you want to index and how. There simply is not a sensible default.

As for the library, you'll need the MySQL Connector/J jar from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: Not entirely true. U might want to keep some un-indexed data in SOLR. For easy fetching, why do a call to SOLR and then another call to DB to fetch all the other fields (which can span more than one table)

Comment: Sure, you can always decide to keep copies of your data in Solr for easy access - but not everyone wants to do that, so Solr leaves the choice to you.

Comment: @WanderNauta: All the sites tell to register the dih in solrconfig.xml. I am working in Ubuntu do I need to erase entire solrconfig.xml in the example folder and then add the DIH
                           OR
 should I just add to the file with the remaining sample data>

Comment: You should add to the file.